# Microsoft jscript runtime erroe Object Required

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am not getting any error in my application but when I run it and click on a button then jscript runtime error object reqired happens with the option of break and continue...

How can it be solved??

Comment: @Srivastava if its urgent you need to edit your question and place some code.

Comment: this error i m getting only when run with IE but the program is running good in firefox..

Comment: Can anyone plz suggest me the issue...

Comment: @Srivastava : Pls give the code which throws error.

Comment: I am fetting error inthe following .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the error due to null value.It may happen when u r calling a function which is not defined or may be there will be mismatch of braces in ur javascript.If you are using jquery,then sometimes you will forget to give the refernce to jquery[js file].Please check ur javascript or check whether u given all scripts correctly